# Validation Parameter Get Method in fuelphp

Tags: php, validation, fuelphp

i have a problem when i want to validate using GET Method in fuelphp

i'm looking up in [this documentation](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/validation/validation.html#usage)

```
// run validation on just post
if ($val->run())
{
    // process your stuff when validation succeeds
}
else
{
    // validation failed
}
```

that's code only validate if the method is Post or default post.

how to validate method get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the validation against an array:

```
if ($val->run( array( $validation_rule => $value_to_validate) ))  
{  
     // process your stuff when validation succeeds  
}
else  
{
     // validation failed
}
```

Example:

```
$val = Validation::factory();
$val->add('email')->add_rule('valid_email');

if ($val->run( array('email'=>$email) ))
{
    // $email is valid
}
else
{
    // $email is not valid
}
```

Comment: `$email` is `Input::get('email');` ?